# macOS Ventura Xcode 14, unable to use self signed provisioning profile, "Profile is missing the required UUID property."

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, provisioning-profile

I am using a self signed provisioning profile, made with this tutorial: https://dkimitsa.github.io/2018/01/04/ios-homemade-provision-profile/

This was working great until i've updated to macOS Ventura (macOS 13.0), it has removed my self made provisioning profile and does not let me install it again.

[image]

Comment: Ok so according to this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3125-inside-code-signing-provisioning-profiles the issue might be that they use DER-Encoded-Profile as the only source of truth from now on, and this is not taken into account in the tutorial I've posted.